# emguCV 3.1 - face detection

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-detection

I'm new to OpenCV/EmguCV in C#. 
I tried a tutorial (http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/level-3---live-face-detection) and the video captureing with the webcam was easy. Now my problem:
The tutorial was written for EmguCV 2.x. I'm using EmguCV 3.1 (I like to use the newest). Therefor I used the class `Mat` instead of the class `Image<>`. The class `Image<>` hasn't worked with `capture.QueryFrame();` 
But when I come to face detection, the tutorial says I should use the classes `CascadeClassifier` and `DetectHaarCascade`. `CascadeClassifier` is accepted but `DetectHaarCascade` is not known. 
In my 5-hour!! search I just found out, that DetectHaarCascade is obsolete but didn't find any methods replacing it exept `HaarCascade.Detect()` which is also not known.

I have following assamblies:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
```

So, please help me: What is the replacement for DetectHaarCascade and how do I use it? Is there any tutorial for EmguCV 3.1?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Get a look at the [example for face detection](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/FaceDetection) / DetectFace.cs:

Important are:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
```

and:

```
IInputArray image, 
String faceFileName, String eyeFileName,
List<Rectangle> faces
using( CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier( faceFileName ) )
{
    using( UMat ugray = new UMat() )
    {
        CvInvoke.CvtColor( image, ugray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray );

        //normalizes brightness and increases contrast of the image
        CvInvoke.EqualizeHist( ugray, ugray );

        //Detect the faces  from the gray scale image and store the locations as rectangle                   
        Rectangle[] facesDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(
           ugray, 1.1, 10, new Size( 20, 20 ) );

        faces.AddRange( facesDetected );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

henne959, I am also fairly new to emgu c# - but have been around the opencv realm a little.  First thing to realize is that it evolves.  Names change. So keep an open mind.  I recently played around with face detection a la emgu c# (3.0) and found the tutorial you mentioned.  The *CascadeClassifier* class is there.  But, I found the HAAR detector (that I wanted to use) manifest as an extension to that class:  *DetectMultiScale*

Among the links I noted while researching this topic - these two were among my favorite (sorry - I don't have the rep points to include more links)
http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/level-3c---how-to-improve-face-detection
http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2013/10/21/face-detection-for-net-using-emgucv/

These two lines of code will probably help you tie the pieces together

```
CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(@"C:\OPENCV_3.0.0\opencv\build\etc\haarcascades\" + "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

Rectangle RectFaces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(tMat, 1.03, 1, new Size(tMat.Width/13, tMat.Height/13), new Size((int)((double)tMat.Width/1.05), (int)((double)tMat.Width / 1.05)));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is the thing I looked for! The link between detecthaarcascade and detectmultiscale was missing in my search... :-D

Answer (score 2):

To convert `Mat` into `Image<>` use `ToString()` method and use `CascadeClassifier` instead of `HaarCascade`.

Answer (score 1):

*Emgu.CV* is an open source project. You can find it on *sourceforce.com*. They also have [git repository here](https://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/). You can clone it in your computer.

This repository also includes sample projects (in *Emgu.CV.Example* folder).

p.s. I can't tell you exactly which class you need, however you can check the sample project called *FaceDetection*. They are using **CascadeClassifier** and **CudaCascadeClassifier** classes. Hope this helps.