# Using Emgu.CV To Detect Faces From Webcam (C#)

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-detection

I'm building a test application in C# to detect faces from a webcam and

I've built it as a Windows Form with a Timer (`timer1`), a Picture Box for displaying the webcam output (`pictureBox1`) and a Textbox for displaying the number of faces (`textBox2`). I have installed EmguCV through NuGet (v3.1.0.1) and set everything up. Most of the tutorials for EmguCV are for an earlier version, and the necessary `HaarCascade` class has been depreciated. However, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394522/emgucv-3-1-face-detection) provided me with the necessary updates to my code.

I now have everything set up to work. The webcam displays an updating image in `pictureBox1`. The detector is *supposed* to work on the webcam frames every time `timer1` ticks over, and the number of rectangles in the `Faces[]` array is outputted as a string to `textBox2`. However, nothing seems to be working. I cannot get it to recognise anything. The program is running, but the number of faces detected always says 0. If I initially set the `NumberOfFaces` variable to something like 5, the Emgu code changes it to 0 in the output. So, something is happening. I'm using the haar xml provided with EmguCV, but no avail. Can anybody help me?

Code dump below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

namespace FaceDetectTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Capture cap;
        public CascadeClassifier haar;
        public int NumberOfFaces;
        public Rectangle[] Faces;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cap = new Emgu.CV.Capture(0);
            haar = new CascadeClassifier(@"C:\Users\Rob\AppData\Roaming\masterbeast\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
            NumberOfFaces = 0;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           using (Image<Bgr, byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
            {
                if (nextFrame != null)
                {
                Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                Faces = haar.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 1, new Size(100, 100), new Size(1000, 1000));
                NumberOfFaces = Faces.Length;

            }

            pictureBox1.Image = nextFrame.ToBitmap();
                textBox2.Text = NumberOfFaces.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same code too, Can you tell me how can I find haarcascade file? I installed EMGU.CV using NuGet package and when I run my code it says that the haarcascade file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

As so often with Stack Overflow, I found a (partial) solution to this some seconds after posting the question.

What seemed to be causing the issue was the conditional statement `if (nextFrame != null)`. I don't know if this has to do with the refresh rate of my webcam, or the `timer1` tickover. Removing this now detects faces, though I need to play around with the parameters of the `DetectMultiScale` method as they only are detected if fully face-on and very close.

If anybody can shed any light on this further, please be my guest; however, it works, and that is all that matters to me. If you are coming here for an example of using Emgu.CV 3.1 for face detection, try the above code without that conditional statement.