# C# Emgu, could not be found Capture and HaarCascade

Tags: c#, emgucv

What did I miss?

VS could not be found Capture and HaarCascade.
I added all opencv .dll and "Copy always".

[image: Copy always]

And added References of Emgu.

[image: References]

My Emgu is emgucv-windesktop 3.2.0.2682-сuda. Visual Studio 2017

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Emgu.CV;
    using Emgu.Util;
    using Emgu.CV.Structure;
    using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace Emgu.FaceDetection
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private Capture cap;
            private HaarCascade haar;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: `HaarCascade` was deprecated a long ago, IIRC.

Comment: @arrowd I use http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection

Comment: @SLaks Visual Studio could not be found Class Capture, HaarCascade

Comment: `Capture` has been renamed to `VideoCapture`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `HaarCascade` when using EmguCV3.X, it has been deprecated and replaced with `CascadeClassifier`

See [here for an explination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394522/emgucv-3-1-face-detection), the summary being it has changed to something akin to this:

```
CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(@"C:\OPENCV_3.0.0\opencv\build\etc\haarcascades\" + "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
```

A more complete example, and tutorial, using 3.X can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319171041/http://ahmedopeyemi.com/main/face-detection-and-recognition-in-c-using-emgucv-3-0-opencv-wrapper-part-1/), a snippet from that blog:

```
private CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier;
_cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
using (var imageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
                {
                    if (imageFrame != null)
                    {
                        var grayframe = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                        var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty); //the actual face detection happens here
                    

foreach (var face in faces)
                    {
                        imageFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.BurlyWood), 3); //the detected face(s) is highlighted here using a box that is drawn around it/them
                       
                    }
                }
                imgCamUser.Image = imageFrame;                    
            }
```